# IEnumerable vs List - which to use (memory & performance)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

I've read quite a few articles about this topic and I'm still confused.
Here's what I know (what I write is related to querying the DB using LINQ):

- AsEnumerable() will execute the query each time I iterate over the collection or invoke some LINQ methods that require enumeration (Min, Max, ToList, FirstOrDefault etc.) - "lazy loading"
- ToList() will execute the query instantly

1. If I perform many operations on the collection, I should use ToList() to avoid querying the DB multiple times. In the following case:

```cs
var test = _context.MyTable.Where(w => w.Conditions...).AsEnumerable(); // db returns 20 records
test.Where(w => w.Conditions); // from 20 records, I only have 10 now
```

Will 20 records be loaded into the memory first, then 10 OR will 10 be loaded from the start? I'm trying to understand when I should use IEnumerable over List (how it works behind the scenes).

2. When all the filtering is done, should I use IEnumerable or List (or it doesn't matter - the performance is similar)?
   Example:

```
var filteredRecords = _context.MyTable.AsNoTracking().Where(...).ToList();
var filteredRecords = _context.MyTable.AsNoTracking().Where(...).AsEnumerable();
```

Which one should I use? FilteredRecords will be sent as a response to the client (Angular for instance)

Comment: I closed it as duplicate of another question about the difference between `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`, because that is basically the part you need to understand. `ToList` always executes a query into materialized results, no matter if it's executed on  IQueryable or on IEnumerable. What matters is the effect on the amount of data pulled from the database as a consequence of query translation.

Answer (score 0):

1. In this case 20 records will be loaded from the database. You can think of `AsEnumerable` as materializing the database query. If you plan to perform further LINQ operations, you should almost always keep the query as an `IQueryable`. Some LINQ operations can't be performed with some database providers, and in such cases, you'll have to use `AsEnumerable` (or rewrite the query).
2. It depends. As you figured out yourself, if you plan to iterate the sequence multiple times you should use `ToList` (or `ToArray` or any other such alternative). If you only plan to iterate it once, it *can* be beneficial to use `AsEnumerable`. Some database providers can perform streaming or buffered reads from the database, and thus does not need to keep all returned records in memory. Which might only be a concern for queries expected to return a large number of records.

Comment: For the second example, I don't plan to iterate over it, I simply return the collection to the client. I noticed that the DB query is executed when I return the response (as in `return Ok(enumerableColection)`). Why should I use AsEnumerable() over ToList() since both will be executed (the timing is not the same)?

Comment: I forgot to thank you for your answer. After reading it several times, I understand that when I plan to iterate over the collection only once (or simply return the collection), I should use IEnumerable. What I'm interested in is why is that the case? I'm asking this because, in the second example, both queries will be executed (the timing is different). Why is IEnumerable more efficient than the List? I use EF Core 3 and SQL Server for my app.

Comment: @RăzvanPuștea IEnumerable isn't more efficient than List, but in some cases it can be less memory intensive. Imagine a query that would return a million records. With `ToList`, all these records would be read into memory before being written to the client stream. With `AsEnumerable`, the database provider *can* batch the database reads, meaning that not all records are ever in memory at the same time. I don't know if the provider for (Microsoft?) SQL Server works like this.

Comment: @Netråm `IEnumerable` doesn't have a database provider, only `IQueryable` does. Only LINQ statements executed on `IQueryable` have a chance of getting translated into SQL. I say *chance* because only a limited number of LINQ operations is supported. It's not correct to say that `AsEnumerable` can be thought of as materializing the database query. It doesn't. `ToList` does. The main effect of `AsEnumerable` is that the contact with the database (or query translation) provider is lost.